# WPF GetIsInDesignMode From Inside A Converter

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, prism

How would i be able to use the GetIsInDesignMode from inside a converter? It seems that the method requires the parent user control/window, a variable which is not accessible when inside a converter.

Example :

```
public class CellImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
          if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(??))
          ..
          ..
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I came across a few answers searching for "DesignerProperties wpf". This method from http://sweux.com/blogs/laranjeira/index.php/wpf/design-mode-wpf/how-to-get-design-mode-property-in-wpf/ is quite simple.

```
DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject());
```